# Vue 3. Как мне передать this в computed?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, this

```
computed: {
...mapGetters(['insurerPersonType']),
...mapGetSet(this.$store, [
    'contractNumber', 'contractDate', 'lastNameLife',
    'nameLife', 'patronymicLife', 'dateOfBirth'
])
```

Мне нужно передать this.$store в функцию mapGetSet. Но при передаче this === undefined. Как выйти из этой ситуации?

Comment: Покажите весь ваш код, вы неправильно используете `Vue` `3` версии. Вы должны работать в контексте `setup()` а не выходить в корень компонента.

Comment: Если я не использую `Composition API`, это не значит, что я использую Vue 3 неправильно. Для чего вам остальной мой код? Проблема заключается только в том, что при передаче this в mapGetSet, он имеет значение undefined. Остальной код тут явно не требуется.

Comment: Вот решение моей проблемы: https://coderoad.ru/54833150/Vue-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-prop-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8-mapFields
Я ещё не тестировал это на своём коде. Сделаю это завтра и если всё пройдёт успешно, то напишу эту ссылку в ответ на свой вопрос.

Comment: Использовать `Vue3` без `CompositionAPI` это как-то странно.

Comment: @MoloF Да, Composition API, может быть лучше, чем стандартный подход, но это не меняет того факта, что НЕ использование Composition API - это НЕ неправильно